# .NET MAUI: How MAUI Will it impact on Xamarin Native applications?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, xamarin-native

I have come to know that Microsoft will not support Xamarin anymore by the end of this year (Nov 2021) in favour of MAUI and .NET MAUI is the next generation of Xamarin Forms as well, so what will happen to Xamarin.Native apps. Will they also be upgraded to MAUI or the change will only have impact on Xamarin Forms, but if it will have on Xamarin Native apps then will we be required to change the complete structure of existing app to the MAUI framework. Please guide in this regard.

Comment: MAUI will replace Forms, but Forms will continue to receive support for one year after MAUI's official release.  Xamarin native should not be impacted.

Comment: @Jason, I am aware of Xamarin Forms, my question was about Xamarin Native I mean Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS......

Comment: And I answered “Xamarin native should not be impacted”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an extract of the [MS announcement blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/#transitioning-from-xamarin-forms-to-net-maui) :

> As part of our .NET unification, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android will become part of .NET 6 as .NET for iOS and .NET for Android. Because these bindings are projections of the SDKs shipped from Apple and Google, nothing changes there, however build tooling, target framework monikers, and runtime framework monikers will be updated to match all other .NET 6 workloads. Our commitment to keeping .NET developers up-to-date with the latest mobile SDKs is foundational to .NET MAUI and remains firm. When .NET 6 ships, we expect to ship a final release of Xamarin SDKs in their current form that will be serviced for a year. All modern work will at that time shift to .NET 6.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment on Xamarin support is incorrect. Once MAUI comes out (November 2021), Xamarin will be supported for one full year, that is, until November 2022.